# Web services over HBase

Tags: web-services, hadoop, hbase

I am new to the Hadoop environment, sorry if the question is obvious... 
I need to develop a web service to record and read large volumes of data. Because of this requirement I thought of using a Hadoop cluster and HBase as my database.

I have designed my hbase schema to satisfy my requirements, so far so good.

The thing is that since it is a service I am developing, I would like the users of the service not to know the internal representation of the data.
I do not want the users to have to invoke a Put to a certain table, for example, to the Clients table, but instead invoke a high-abstraction method, for example, createClient().

How do I add this abstraction layer on top of HBase while maintaining the characteristics of reliable and distributed and the capacity to service lots of users simultaneously offered by HBase itself?

Thanks a lot

Comment: think not just HBase, but how would your/any webservice serve data from datasources like SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Hbase Stargate](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate)  to enable a REST server.  If you want to obscure the table name in the URI, perhaps proxy Stargate with a web server.